# why is there no "Adobe Flash Player" in these searches

Tags: 16.04, firefox, flash, adobe

This [web page](https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSEARCA%3ADIA&ei=38M9Wai8LZOHjAHJ8Ia4Dg) from `finance.google.com` or `www.google.com/finance` says `"Adobe Flash Player"` is required for interactive charts. The application called `"Ubuntu Software"` has a search feature. The application is in the screen shot. It shows that the search turned up no such application. 
[image]
From Firefox I can click on the Add-Ons menu item, then click on "see more add-ons" and then use the search. The search shows no such product.
[image]
What is the canonical way to get this application for Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 2):

*Ubuntu Software* is designed to find and install applications with graphical user interfaces at first hand.

The recommended ways to get Flash on Ubuntu are summarized on this page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html

So, for Firefox, installing the `flashplugin-installer` package may be sufficient.

```
sudo apt install flashplugin-installer
```